# How to scroll one widget at a time in flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll, scrollview, flutter-listview

[image: stepwise widget scroll]

how to achieve this stepwise widget scroll in flutter

Comment: Use swiper package. These are called carousels BTW.

Comment: Thank you @Abbas

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the widget `PageView`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1gE9xvph-A

You insert a list children and set the axis to horizontal